# RSpec and "uninitialized constant Features" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

When I run rspec test I get:

> /home/jasiek/Desktop/katowice-ror-workshops-2015/spec/support/features.rb:2:in `block in ': uninitialized constant Features (NameError)

I suppose problem is only on my local machine because this is repo from trust source (another users haven't got this problem). The repo I'm talking about: https://github.com/netguru-training/katowice-ror-workshops-2015

I read on Stack that the problem could be missing line:

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
```

But I've got it.

Where could be a problem?

And this is a whole log from console:

> jasiek@jasiek-HP-EliteBook-8470p:~/Desktop/katowice-ror-workshops-2015$ RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rspec
>   /home/jasiek/Desktop/katowice-ror-workshops-2015/spec/support/features.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Features (NameError)
>       from /home/jasiek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.0/lib/rspec/core.rb:97:in`configure'
>       from /home/jasiek/Desktop/katowice-ror-workshops-2015/spec/support/features.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
>       from /home/jasiek/Desktop/katowice-ror-workshops-2015/spec/rails_helper.rb:23:in`block in '
>       from /home/jasiek/Desktop/katowice-ror-workshops-2015/spec/rails_helper.rb:23:in `each'
>       from /home/jasiek/Desktop/katowice-ror-workshops-2015/spec/rails_helper.rb:23:in`'
>       from /home/jasiek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1280:in `require'
>       from /home/jasiek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1280:in`block in requires='
>       from /home/jasiek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1280:in `each'
>       from /home/jasiek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1280:in`requires='
>       from /home/jasiek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:109:in `block in process_options_into'
>       from /home/jasiek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:108:in`each'
>       from /home/jasiek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:108:in `process_options_into'
>       from /home/jasiek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:21:in`configure'
>       from /home/jasiek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:101:in `setup'
>       from /home/jasiek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:88:in`run'
>       from /home/jasiek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in `run'
>       from /home/jasiek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:41:in`invoke'
>       from /home/jasiek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.0/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
>       from /home/jasiek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/bin/rspec:23:in`load'
>       from /home/jasiek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
>       from /home/jasiek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`eval'
>       from /home/jasiek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `'

Answer (score 4):

I know its late.

But for other people who may come here for searching the answer. I was facing the same issue. 
So when I checked `rails_helper.rb` file inside spec I found that this line

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
```

was commented initially so I un-commented  it and everything worked fine.
I am using

```
gem 'capybara', '~> 2.15', '>= 2.15.4'
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.6'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following in your `spec/support/features.rb` file:

```
require '../../spec/support/features/session_helpers'
```

So, it becomes:

```
require '../../spec/support/features/session_helpers'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Features::SessionHelpers, type: :feature
end
```

Comment: Thanks. But now I get: `/home/jasiek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in require: cannot load such file -- ../../spec/support/features/session_helpers (LoadError)`

Comment: I cant reproduce that issue locally. I cloned the repo and I dont get that error when I run the tests (even without `require '../../spec/support/features/session_helpers'`)